# setInterval in ES6 object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, methods, setinterval

I have the following object. I works until I use setinterval . 
I realise that `this` becomes the object `timeout`

```
class test{
    constructor(){
        this.counter = 0
    }
    startCounter(){
        this.increment()
       setInterval(this.increment, 1000)
    }
    increment(){
        this.counter++
        console.log(this.counter)
    }

}

var t = new test()
t.startCounter()
```

Outputs:

```
1
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) suggest that I should use `var self = this` but ES6 does not support private variables

Comment: @T.J Crowder This link has no ES6 objects. I do not see is this a duplicate

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with "ES6 objects." It has to do with `this`. If you take the time to read the answers, you'll understand.

Comment: Maybe the solution is the same but the scenario is different @T.J. Crowder

Comment: It says I should use var self = this but ES6 does not support private variables

Comment: @JoseMato - Again, doesn't matter.

Comment: @TSR You haven't read all of the accepted answer on the linked question. It gives several solutions for several scenarios. The solutions under the headings "Explicitly set `this` of the callback - part 1" and "ECMAScript 6: Use arrow functions" would both solve your problem neatly.

Comment: @TSR - The answers there say a lot more than that. Take the time to actually read through the answers and digest what they're saying, rather than focussing on the idea that this isn't covered there and giving up after 30 seconds. This is **well-covered** in the answers there, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/157247).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```js
class test{
    constructor(){
        this.counter = 0
    }
    startCounter(){
        this.increment()
       setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000)
    }
    increment(){
        this.counter++
        console.log(this.counter)
    }

}

var t = new test()
t.startCounter()
```

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Comment: maybe you should add `()=>this.increment()` as the title mentioned `es6`, though.

Comment: @appleapple - All of which is covered by the linked dupetarget. Which is part of why Yet Another Answer to this question is not useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that answer is way too complicate to become an answer to this question IMHO. and this answer has nothing wrong (well, it lack some explanation and es6 stuff, so I didn't upvote it).

Comment: T.J. Crowder Thank you for your feedback. I think stackoverflow is a wonderful place where people are learning from each others.